# Mobilefirst 7.1 and Swift

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst

May I add a swift class to my mobile first 7.1 ios project ? Moreover can this swift class to be a Cordova Plugin ?

Comment: Nothing stops you from adding a swift class to an iOS Project. Can you be more clear with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general IBM mobilefirst platform is certified for up to Swift 2.3, however if your plan is to implement a custom Cordova plugin for your project then this is not really related to MFP...

Comment: So Shouldn't I expect any issue invoking MFP API from a native Swift plugin ? I mean for example the objc - swift bridge.

Comment: 7.1 provides the bridge built in.